# Unknown Micropohne can hear unknown person (weird)

Tags: security, skype, webcam, vlc, microphone

I tried to capture a video using webcam and VLC.

On Menu I select "open capture device".

VLC then presents my webcam and 4 audio devices named hw:0,0, hw:0,2, hw:1,0 and hw:10.

Because I don't know which one is my Headset microphone I simply tested them.

[image: Capture Device Dialog VLC]

And now the weird thing:

**When I choose hw:10 I can hear a unknown person.**

The person clearly doesn't know that he/she is captured by microphone. 
I can hear him/her typing on a keyboard and have some surrounding sound. Sometimes he/she talks with someone in the room. All in a language that I don't know.

Where can this come from?
The only speculation I have is, it has something to do with Skype.

(Because I work with many Freelancers from other countries).

And now the actual question:

**How can I find out, what microphone this is and where it comes from?**

(And how can I make sure nobody else can here ME!?)

EDIT: After firs answer, her is the result of arecord -l:

```
    arecord -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (CAPTURE) ****
Karte 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], Gerät 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], Gerät 2: ALC889 Alt Analog [ALC889 Alt Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 2/2
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
  Sub-Gerät #1: subdevice #1
Karte 1: U0x46d0x825 [USB Device 0x46d:0x825], Gerät 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 3: Headset [Logitech USB Headset], Gerät 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and type this command:

```
arecord -l
```

It will list all your audio recording devices.

If you want to see playback devices:

```
aplay -l
```

Devices are displayed like this:

```
card 0: <name of the card>, device 1: <hardware device>
```

This example shows device `hw:0,1`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I edited the question an posted the result of arecord -l